# SImple form undefined method path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm new at using simple form. In the beginning i wanted to make an easy form.

```
#country_controller
def edit
  @country = Country.find(params[:id])  
end

#edit.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @country do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

But I'm getting this error

```
undefined method `country_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fdb21098e00>:0x007fdb2108cad8>
```

my routes

```
 management GET    /management(.:format)                              management/home#index
             management_settings GET    /management/settings(.:format)                     management/settings#list
        management_country_index GET    /management/country(.:format)                      management/country#index
         edit_management_country GET    /management/country/:id/edit(.:format)             management/country#edit
              management_country PATCH  /management/country/:id(.:format)                  management/country#update
                                 PUT    /management/country/:id(.:format)                  management/country#update
                                 DELETE /management/country/:id(.:format)                  management/country#destroy
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your routing is slightly non-standard you would need to pass the url explicitly to simple_form_for

```
<%= simple_form_for @country, url: management_country_path(@country) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you're using a [`scope`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing):

```
<%= simple_form_for [:management, @country] do |f| %>
```

You could also use a [`polymorphic_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html):

```
<%= simple_form_for @country, url: polymorphic_path([:management, @country]) do |f| %>
```